# Flutter controller listen stream stop after data

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the following in the build widget and because it's in a stream it's always calling the callback, how do I stop the stream once there is data so it only happens once. I tried to dispose of it but that did not work. I also don't have a cancel method.

```
// Conroller and handles the listening
    void _onQRViewCreated(QRViewController controller) {
      setState(() {
        this.controller = controller;
      });
      // Might need to add onError
      controller.scannedDataStream.listen((scanData) {
        setState(() {
          result = scanData;
          widget.qrSuccess(result.code);
        });
      });
    }
```

Comment: `Stream.first` ? the docs say: *"The first element of this stream.

Stops listening to this stream after the first element has been received."*

Comment: so I get The expression doesn't evaluate to a function, so it can't be invoked. that would not work as I need to call the callback also I'm not sure stream first happens when data is recviced or when the stream just runs

Comment: this is not a function, this is a property

Comment: I know so I can't use it unless I'm seeing something

Comment: `Stream s; s.first();` if you are trying to do something like this, you get the error: `"The expression doesn't evaluate to a function, so it can't be invoked"` - basically it is a `Future` so you need to use [Future.then](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Future/then.html) for example

Comment: Any chance you have an example

Comment: `stream.first.then((scanData) {setState(...);});`

Comment: Ohh ok, I was thinking of something else thanks

Comment: @pskink does not work keeps calling everything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this by pausing the camera here is the code

```
controller.scannedDataStream.listen(
        (onData) {
          setState(() {
            controller.pauseCamera();
            result = onData;
            widget.qrSuccess(result.code);
            print(result.code);
          });
        },
        onError: (err) {
          print('Error!');
        },
        cancelOnError: false,
        onDone: () {
          print('Done!');
        },
      );
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `first` property of stream

```
    void _onQRViewCreated(QRViewController controller) async{
    setState(() {
      this.controller = controller;
    });

    final scanData = await controller.scannedDataStream.first;
    controller.scannedDataStream.close();
    setState(() {
      result = scanData;
      widget.qrSuccess(result.code);
    });
  }
```

Comment: This does not stop it keeps calling it not sure what your trying to do here

Comment: Pause the camera like you did, then close the stream